# Needs help regarding Fullcalendar (increase Time slots per hour)

Tags: asp.net, fullcalendar

Please help me in increasing time slots per hour. in my Fullcalendar control its showing 15 minutes gap per hour mins their are 4 slots of 15 minutes, but i needs slots of 5 minutes. please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/slotMinutes/